# How geolocalisate a new image with a polygon (JSON file)

Tags: qgis, polygon, georeferencing, sentinel-1

I am new using QGIS. I got an Sentinel-1 image from Copernicus I downloaded it as TIFF. I did Python code to detect water so now l have a new plot. I would like this plot gets the same coordinate than the image to do so I can use the polygon from the first image to add a localization to my plot.
I saw on QGIS the window georeference but I need the GCP points but I have only my polygons.

Summary: I would like that my new image (plot) get the same coordinates than my Sentinel-1 image.